# Find the key with the largest number of values and print its values (dictionary, python)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Suppose we have a dict,

```
   dict = {'blue': ['sky','sea'], 'orange': ['carrots','sunset','oranges'], 'green': ['grass']}
```

the output should be

```
['carrots','sunset','oranges']
```

since its got the largest number of values.

This is what I have so far:

```
for k,v in dict.items():
    print(max(k,len(v)))
```

Comment: Good question, but it would be helpful if you showed the output/error that you get when you run the code that you currently have.

Answer (score 9):

Why not just:

```
>>> d = {'blue': ['sky','sea'], 'orange': ['carrots','sunset','oranges'], 'green': ['grass']}
>>> print max(d.values(), key=len)
['carrots', 'sunset', 'oranges']
```

It's best not to name a dictionary `dict` as well. This will override the built-in type.

Comment: This looks like the way that I would do it if I was having a smart programming day :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the title asks for they key - here's how to do it

```
>>> d = {'blue': ['sky','sea'], 'orange': ['carrots','sunset','oranges'], 'green': ['grass']}
>>> max_key = max(d, key=lambda k: len(d[k]))
>>> max_key
'orange'
```

once you have the key, it's quicker to look it up than to iterate the d.values() - assuming you really did need the key too

```
>>> d[max_key]
['carrots', 'sunset', 'oranges']
```

Alternatively, you can just pull out a tuple containing the key/value pair

```
>>> max(d.items(), key=lambda i :len(i[1]))
('orange', ['carrots', 'sunset', 'oranges'])
```

Comment: This is a good answer.  I'll add that if you're doing this inside a loop, you probably shouldn't - it'll tend to yield an O(n^2) algorithm or worse.  If you are doing it inside a loop, and your dictionary is large, you probably should look at trees and/or heaps.